# Скрипт работает только в inspect

Tags: javascript, wordpress

На компютере в браузере слайдер начинает крутиться только в developer tools. Внизу я указал порядок подключения скриптов... почему так происходит ? simplyscroll.js должен крутить этот слайдер, а делает только в inspect

```
function my_scripts() {
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
      wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/style.css' );
 
      wp_enqueue_script( 'simplyscroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/assets/vendor/simplyscroll.js', array('jquery'), wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ) );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'child-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/assets/theme.js', array('jquery'), wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ) );

    }
```

Comment: Скорее всего, в dev tools отключён кеш. Потому изменения видны.

Comment: @KAGG Design Просто не только у меня так ....